# $O(n)\cong SO(n)\rtimes O(1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, semidirect-product

I want to prove that $O(n)\cong SO(n)\rtimes O(1)$ as Lie groups.

I have the following result:

> If $G,N,H$ are Lie groups, then $G\cong N\rtimes H$ iff there are Lie group homomorphisms $\phi:G\to H$ and $\psi:H\to G$ such that $\phi\circ\psi=\mathrm{Id}_H$ and $\ker\phi\cong N$.

Since $O(1)\cong C_2$, we can take $\phi=\det$, which is a Lie group homomorphism with kernel $SO(n)$.

But I am unsure how to find a suitable $\psi$. I thought about something like $\psi(x)=xI$, but then $\phi\circ\psi(x)=x^n$, so is not the identity map if $n$ is even. Can anyone suggest a $\psi$?

Comment: Well, you have that $O(1)=\{\pm1 \}$, what about $$\pm 1\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\pm 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$ ? (where $1_{n-1}$ is the identity matrix in $\mbox{GL}_{n-1}$)

Comment: @Alessandro That works - thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The embedding of $C_2$ into $O(n)$ maps $1$ to $I,$ and $-1$ to the diagonal matrix whose top diagonal element is $-1,$ and the other diagonal elements are $1.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $O_1=\pm 1$ and consider the map $\phi:O_n \to O_1$ by the determinant map and $\psi:O_1 \to O_n$ by $\pm 1 \mapsto \pm Id$. Then we have $\psi \circ \phi = id_{O_1}$ and $ker \phi = SO(n)$. Also these are Lie group homomorphisms (smooth) because $O_n, O_1$ are embedded subgroups so restrictions become smooth as well. Therefore, we obtain the result.